# Magento addAttrtibuteToFilter() not working

Tags: magento-1.9, php

OK, so I'm in the related.phtml page and I'm trying to load in the realeted products only those who are in stock. So there was this code already in the page:

```
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
       ->addCategoryFilter($category)
       ->setCurPage(0)
       ->addAttributeToSelect('*') // add all attributes - optional
       ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1) // enabled
       ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)      
       ->setPageSize(4);
```

and I want to filter with the products that are in stock. So I'm adding another one filter in the code:

```
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
         ->addCategoryFilter($category)
         ->setCurPage(0)
         ->addAttributeToSelect('*') // add all attributes - optional
         ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1) // enabled
         ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)             
         ->joinField('qty',
             'cataloginventory/stock_item',
             'qty',
             'product_id=entity_id',
             '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
             'left')
         ->setPageSize(4);
```

but it still brings me products that are out of stock. I also try this:

```
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
      ->addCategoryFilter($category)
      ->setCurPage(0)
      ->addAttributeToSelect('*') // add all attributes - optional
      ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1) // enabled
      ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)    
     ->addAttributeToFilter('is_in_stock', array('eq' => '1'))        
     ->setPageSize(4);
```

but I still get product that are out of stock. What is wrong with the code?

Thank you

**EDIT:** I've also set the Display out of stock products to No in the Admin Panel in Catalog->Inventory

Comment: Do you have done reindexing?

Answer (score 3):

Below code will return you the products of a category that have

**=> status => Enable**

**=> Visibility => catalog,search**

**=> Stock Availability => In stock**

```
    $cat_id = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId‌​(); 
   $productDetails    = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat_id)
                          ->getProductCollection()
                          ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
   $productDetails -> addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array('in' => array(4) ));
   $productDetails -> addAttributeToFilter('status', array('in' => array(1) ));
   $productDetails->joinField('is_in_stock',
                'cataloginventory/stock_item',
                'is_in_stock',
                'product_id=entity_id',
                'is_in_stock=1',
                '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                'left');
```

Comment: Thank yoy.!  how do I get $cat_id variable  ?

Comment: found it    $cat_id = Mage::registry('current_category')->getId();    It's still not working..... :-(

Comment: Thank for the reply. It returns the products but I was wondering if it only returns configurable products.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
    $productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
           ->addCategoryFilter($category)
           ->setCurPage(0)
           ->addAttributeToSelect('*') // add all attributes - optional
           ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1) // enabled
           ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)      
           ->setPageSize(4);
    // you already have above code now add this
    $productCollection->getSelect()->join('cataloginventory_stock_status', 'cataloginventory_stock_status.product_id = e.entity_id', array('stock_status'));
    $productCollection->getSelect()->where("`cataloginventory_stock_status`.`stock_status` = 1");
```